# CSS position: absolute screen resolution problem

Tags: html, css

CSS code:

```
top:45;
left:98;
float:right;
position:absolute;z-index:2;
```

I have done the above coding for a floating `div` when I was working on 1024 resolution, but when I tested the same on a different resolution it's out of alignment.

How can we fix it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned according to either a relatively positioned ancestor or the window.  It sounds like in your case, it's being positioned in the window.

The way to fix this is to put your absolutely positioned `<div>` inside a relative container.  That way, as the window changes size, it will stay in the correct spot:

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 98px; top: 45px;">
         This div will always be 98px from the left and 45px from the top of its parent .
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is still helpful in 2020 @Pat. I forgot to set `position: relative` to `div` as a result the element was positioned to the window. I spent two days looking for the problem until I land here. I am quite confident to get used with CSS positions. Thanks again

Comment: Glad it was able to help you out @Niyongabo :)

Answer (score 8):

None of the above solutions work for me...
keep it on **absolute position** and give **margin-top, margin-left**...in **%age** like;

```
margin-top:10%;
margin-left:5%;
```

that will **automatically** adjust w.r.t. screen resolution...

this worked perfect for me. tested on different resolutions.

have a fun!

Comment: This did not work for me. I have a single div I am attempting to position absolutely while allowing it to react to resizing of the window.

Comment: @Aaron what problem you are facing can you reproduce it on jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pixel, use the `%`. It may help you to produce the output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the element is not contained within another element with a position of relative, the element you are positioning should be in the same position regardless of resolution.

Make sure you use:

```
top: 45px
left: 98px
```

You left the pixel declaration off in your code above.

Also, float:right is not required on the positioned element, as position:absolute will take it out of the normal flow of the document anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue but it resovled by adding width 100% to the parent div.