# Absolute position not working properly screen resolution changes and window size changes

Tags: html, css

Please refer below code

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 18px;">
        <img id="ImgTachoMetre" src="/Images/u174_normal.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

i have done the above coding for positioing the div element in some required place  of the page.

but when I tested the same on a different resolution it's out of alignment. and when i maximize or minmize the window that time also it's out of alignment.

googled and found similar question in below link

[CSS position: absolute screen resolution problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298720/css-position-absolute-screen-resolution-problem)

but that solution also not working for me.

How can we fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Add this:  `<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 18px; right:10px;">` (also i did not downvote...)

Comment: @downvoter what's wrong in my question ? what need to be improved ?

Comment: @Nico how the "right:10px" will works in all cases in all resolutions ?

Comment: when you define the spaceing to the right edge, the container width will be responsive to the size of the screen. It will only leave a space of 10px to the right. (if the position:relative; container is not styled to prevent this)

Comment: @Nico Thanks, but i tried your solution not working.same results only

Comment: Then something else is wrong or i did not understand what you want to achieve. Please provide a demo in JSfiddle or something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47840/discussion-between-sivarajini-and-nico-o)

Answer (score 0):

use @media only screen in css.

```
<div class="container-style">
<div class="mystyle">
    <img id="ImgTachoMetre" src="/Images/u174_normal.png">
</div>
```

Refer this link --> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px){

.container-style{
 /* Styles */
                }
.mystyle{
 /* Styles */
        }
}




@media only screen 
and (max-width : 1224px){

.container-style{
 /* Styles */
                }
.mystyle{
 /* Styles */
        }
}
```